# PyTorch equivalent of scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres

Tags: python, pytorch, scipy, jax

I'm using scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres to efficiently solve `A.x = b`, however my problem is within the PyTorch framework. So, I have to detach my tensors to `numpy` then call `scipy` to solve this equation. However, other frameworks (like JAX) have their own equivalent function, `jax.scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres`.

Is there a PyTorch equivalent to `scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres` to sparsely solve `A.x = b`?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/47918), if up to date, suggests that the feature doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to that issue, it does indeed seem like it doesn't exist yet. Thanks once again!